# Ayuda con configuracion de PHPMailer para envios de correos con imagenes incrustadas

Tags: php, phpmailer, php7

les comento poseo la siguiente function en php

```
<?php 

 $logo = '<img src="https://local.jesuministrosymas.com.ve/image/LOGO.png" width="180" height="30"><br><br>';
    $footer_correo = '<br>Aca va el Footer del Correo';

function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo) {
    global $footer_correo, $logo;

        require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Encoding = "base64";
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->MsgHTML($cuerpo);
$mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
        //or more succinctly:

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    $mail->Username = 'MI CORREO'; //Modificar
    $mail->Password = 'MI CLAVE'; //Modificar


//User Email to use for SMTP authentication - Use the same Email used in Google Developer Console
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "MI CORREO";

    $mail->setFrom('MI CORREO', 'NOMBRE'); //Modificar
    $mail->addAddress($email, $nombre);

    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $logo. $cuerpo . $footer_correo;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

        //send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
    }
?>
```

En el script de prueba tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
    $email = "MI CORREO";
    $nombre = "Jose";
    $asunto = "Prueba de Contenido";
    $cuerpo = $contenido;
    enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo); 
    $_SESSION['editar_contenido']  .= '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Hemos enviado Un correo a MI CORREO<br>';
?>
```

La variable $contenido se esta obteniendo de un input que a su vez se esta almacenando en mi base de datos MySQL y posee un editor que me brinda salidas combinada de texto e imagenes tanto PNG como JPG el formato es algo como:

```
$contenido = "<p>Esta es una Prueba numero 5 Modificacion Actual 05</p><p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" data-filename="Logo-bod-390x269.jpg" style="width: 390px;"><br></p>";
```

En mi base de datos se almacena de manera perfecta pero al correo tal cual como tengo mi configuracion actual.

**EL PROBLEMA**
 El problema que presenta mi script es que en correo que envía esta llegando la imagen como un archivo adjunto y no muestra en el contenido la imagen incrustada en dicho contenido.
Alguno puede orientarme sobre la correcta configuración que debe tener mi function **enviarEmail()**
 He modificado mi function y ahora la imagen contenida en la variable $contenido llega al correo pero como un archivo adjunto es decir no se muestra en el contenido propio del correo como si sucede con el logo de la variable $logo
**Imagen de como llega el mensaje**
[image: Como llega el mensaje a mi correo]

Comment: Pero que pasa, que error tienes, que no hace, nos explicaste todo menos el problema

Comment: hasta donde se no puedes enviarla como base 64, debes decodificarla primero

Comment: Gracias por contestar, @AlbertoSiurob he editado mi consullta, he separado mi problema con el titulo **EL PROBLEMA**

Comment: Gracias por escribir @CarlosQuintero como hago la decodificacion porque he visto ejemplos de como hacerlo cuando la imagen sola es una variable aparte, como debo hacerlo cuando en una misma variable va incrustada la imagen sea JPEG/PNG aplico la function de decodificacion a toda la variable **$contenido**..? o hay una forma de hacerlo mediante alguna funcion a implementar en mi function **enviarEmail()**

Comment: Creo que tienes que usar el método **[`addStringEmbeddedImage()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringEmbeddedImage)** pasándole los parámetros indicados. La diferencia con `addEmbeddedImage` está en el primer parámetro, que sería la información binaria de la imagen, en lugar de la ruta del mismo. Creo que es lo que necesitas, puesto que dispones de la imagen en base64.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por tu siempre atenta ganas de ayudar.. pero no se como implementar el metodo ya que he intentado hacerlo directamente aplicandolo a la variable $contenido y da error y no envia el correo..!

Comment: He implementado la siguiente linea de instruccione a mi Function **enviarEmail()** `$mail->Encoding = "base64";
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->MsgHTML($cuerpo);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);` y ahora el correo que llega la imagen esta adjunta en el Email pero no aparece en el contenido del correo..!!